# Error: Unable to access jarfile avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.3.0.jar

Tags: cloudera, avro, getschema

i am trying to import data into hive from the data imported in sqoop.
below is the link from where i am trying to execute the commands
when i tried to execute below command

> **java -jar avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.3.0.jar getschema part-m-00000.avro** **>**
>   **customer.avsc**

it gives error

> **Error: Unable to access jarfile avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.3.0.jar**

http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2015/05/importing-data-from-sqoop-into-hive.html

i have setup virtualbox using cloudera template.

can anybody help in identifying what is missing either in configuration or command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path of avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.3.0.jar file needs to be specified in the command. and it worked.

Sample Command

```
java -jar /usr/lib/avro/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.3.0.jar getschema part-m-00000.avro > customer.avsc
```